# How to listen/intercept phone calls for Oreo onward?

Tags: android, android-service, android-8.0-oreo, android-background

How to listen Phone calls for Android version Oreo onward [limits for background service](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#services). Looking for working examples.

Note: Application may not be in foreground state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution !

Actually action **android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"** is a part of implicit broadcast exceptions, so shouldn't have any issues registering broadcast receiver. It will still work.

I was missing permission android.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS while asking other two permissions 1)READ_PHONE_STATE and 2) CALL_PHONE at run time, declaring in manifest was not enough.

We must have to include all below permissions in manifest file as well as asking permissions at run-time 1) android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE 2) android.permission.CALL_PHONE 3) android.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS [this is important, and needed for Android 8.0 Oreo (API 26+)]